# ¿Como puedo operar con elementos con id dinámicos en jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Mi pregunta nace de la necesidad de trabajar con `inputs` dentro de un formulario, cuyos elementos son generados dinámicamente por **php** (cada fila contiene las notas de un estudiante, es decir n filas), este `form` hace parte de una planilla de notas, el usuario debe introducir las notas y se debe mostar el calculo de la nota definitiva en otro elemento, en tiempo real, para esto cree un **js** con `ajax` que llama a un **script php**, el cual realiza el cálculo, pero el inconveniente es, como puedo indicar en el js los inputs de entrada si sus nombres son dinámicos? adjunto parte del **script php** del form y el **js**

```
<?php  
            $i=1;
                    foreach ($listEstudiantes as $persona) { 
                    ?>
                      <tr style="padding: 1px;">
                        <td style="font-size: 10px;"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                        <td colspan="7" style="font-size: 11px; text-align:left; width: 180px;"><?php echo strtoupper($persona['primer_apellido_est'])." ".strtoupper($persona['segundo_apellido_est'])." ".strtoupper($persona['primer_nombre_est'])." ".strtoupper($persona['segundo_nombre_est']); ?></td>

                        <!-- Actividades Psicomotor -->
                        <form name="actPsi" id="actPsi" method="post">
                        <?php 
                        if (empty($listActPsi)) {
                           echo "<td></td>"; 
                           echo "<td></td>"; 
                           echo "<td></td>"; 
                           echo "<td></td>"; 
                           echo "<td></td>"; 
                           echo "<td></td>"; 
                           echo "<td></td>"; 

                        }else{
                            $title_p1 = (array_key_exists(0, $listActPsi)) ? "'Actividad: ".$listActPsi[0]['nombre_actividad']." / ".$listActPsi[0]['porcentaje_act']."%' " : "'No hay actividad registrada' readonly";
                            $title_p2 = (array_key_exists(1, $listActPsi)) ? "'Actividad: ".$listActPsi[1]['nombre_actividad']." / ".$listActPsi[1]['porcentaje_act']."%' " : "'No hay actividad registrada' readonly";
                            $title_p3 = (array_key_exists(2, $listActPsi)) ? "'Actividad: ".$listActPsi[2]['nombre_actividad']." / ".$listActPsi[2]['porcentaje_act']."%' " : "'No hay actividad registrada' readonly";
                            $title_p4 = (array_key_exists(3, $listActPsi)) ? "'Actividad: ".$listActPsi[3]['nombre_actividad']." / ".$listActPsi[3]['porcentaje_act']."%' " : "'No hay actividad registrada' readonly";
                            $title_p5 = (array_key_exists(4, $listActPsi)) ? "'Actividad: ".$listActPsi[4]['nombre_actividad']." / ".$listActPsi[4]['porcentaje_act']."%' " : "'No hay actividad registrada' readonly";
                            echo "<td><input type='text' style='width:24px; height:18px; font-size:10px;' name='actPsi_1_[".$persona['id_estudiante']."]' id='actPsi_1_[".$persona['id_estudiante']."]' pattern='[0-9]+([,\.][0-9]+)?'  value=0 title=".$title_p1." min='10' max='100'></td>"; 
                            echo "<td><input type='text' style='width:24px; height:18px; font-size:10px;' name='actPsi_2_[".$persona['id_estudiante']."]' id='actPsi_2_[".$persona['id_estudiante']."]' pattern='[0-9]+([,\.][0-9]+)?' value=0 title=".$title_p2." min='10' max='100'></td>"; 
                            echo "<td><input type='text' style='width:24px; height:18px; font-size:10px;' name='actPsi_3_[".$persona['id_estudiante']."]' id='actPsi_3_[".$persona['id_estudiante']."]' pattern='[0-9]+([,\.][0-9]+)?' value=0 title=".$title_p3." min='10' max='100'></td>"; 
                            echo "<td><input type='text' style='width:24px; height:18px; font-size:10px;' name='actPsi_4_[".$persona['id_estudiante']."]' id='actPsi_4_[".$persona['id_estudiante']."]' pattern='[0-9]+([,\.][0-9]+)?' value=0 title=".$title_p4." min='10' max='100'></td>"; 
                            echo "<td><input type='text' style='width:24px; height:18px; font-size:10px;' name='actPsi_5_[".$persona['id_estudiante']."]' id='actPsi_5_[".$persona['id_estudiante']."]' pattern='[0-9]+([,\.][0-9]+)?' value=0 title=".$title_p5." min='10' max='100'></td>"; 
                            echo "<td><span style='font-style:bold; font-size:10px;' name='DN_P' id='DN_P' title='Definitiva Numérica Psicomotor'> </span> <input type='hidden' name='DefNum' id='DefNum' /></td>"; 
                            echo "<td><input type='text' style='width:29px; height:18px; font-size:10px;' name='DC_P' id='DC_P' pattern='[0-9]+([,\.][0-9]+)?' title='Definitiva Conceptual Psicomotor' readonly></td>"; 
                        }

                        ?>
                        </form>
                        <!-- Actividades Psicomotor -->
```

Este es el script js -ajax, me funciona con id estáticos, pero no se como hacer con inputs con id dinámico.

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){       
    $('#actPsi_1,#actPsi_2,#actPsi_3,#actPsi_4,#actPsi_5').change(function(){
        var url = "calculo.php";
        $.ajax({                        
           type: "POST",                 
           url: url,                     
           data: $("#actPsi").serialize(), 
           success: function(data)             
           {
             $('#DN_P').html(data);
             $('#DefNum').val(data);
           }
       });
     });
});
```

Comment: ¿El evento `on('change')` sería para todos uts inputs de texto? Con que hagas algo como `$('input:text').on('change', function(){})` así no te preocupas por buscar por ids. Y otra cosa el poner un llamado ajax cada que el input cambie te creará enormes cuellos de botella y llamadas al servidor innecesarias, si puedes pasar la lógica de tu php a JS te ahorrarías mucho tráfico en tu red.

Comment: @JavierMD, no te sirvió mi respuesta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tenes varias formas de seleccionar elementos en jquery, no solo a través de su ID, primero deberías leer un poco sobre los selectores:

**El selector Id**

Selecciona un elemento del DOM a través de su Id

```
<div id="algunid"></div>
<script>
    var elemento = $("#algunid");
</script>
```

**El selector clase**

Selecciona un o mas elementos del DOM a través de su clase

```
<div class="main"></div>
<script>
    var elementosArray = $(".main");
</script>
```

**El selector elemento**

Selecciona un o mas elementos del DOM a través del tipo de element

```
<div class="main"></div>
<div id="algo"></div>
<script>
    var elementosArray = $("div");
</script>
```

**Combinaciones**

podes combinar tal cual lo hace el css para elegir elementos

```
<div class="main"></div>
<p class="main"></p>
<script>
    //seleccionar solo el div con clase main
    var elemento = $("div.main");
</script>
```

**Solución**

Tenes varias soluciones, podrias selecionar la tabla y cada uno de sus inputs

```
$("#actPsi > input");
```

O, para mi la mas sencilla, agregar una clase de control

```
<input type='text' class="calculo"...
<script>
    $('.calculo').change(function(){
    ...
```

Aquí tenes un tutorial para los selectores: http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/selectors/introduction/

Espero te haya ayudado, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

En el caso creo que seria mas acertado cambiar algunos aspectos de la forma en que se esta imprimiendo el input para poder generalizar el evento `change`.

Como sugerencia quitar el id que no veo la necesidad de establecerlo puesto que modificando el name a algo mas general por ejemplo a `name='actPsi_1'` se puede acceder a el con la ayuda de jQuery de esta forma

`$("[name=actPsi_1]").change(function(){
....
})`

jQuery adjunta el evento change a todos los input con el name indicado.

Y para obtener el id del estudiante puedes agregar un atributo de tipo `data-` asi: `data-id-estudiante='".$persona['id_estudiante']."'` para poder tener el id en el evento change

`$("[name=actPsi_1]").change(function(){
  var idEstudiante = $(this).attr("data-id-estudiante");
})`

Para agregar todos los elementos con un change debes separarlos por comas:

`$("[name=actPsi_1],[name=actPsi_2],[name=actPsi_3],[name=actPsi_4],[name=actPsi_5]").change(function(){
  var idEstudiante = $(this).attr("data-id-estudiante");
})`

Quedando los echo:

```
echo "<td><input type='text' style='width:24px; height:18px; font-size:10px;' name='actPsi_1' data-id-estudiante='".$persona['id_estudiante']."' pattern='[0-9]+([,\.][0-9]+)?'  value=0 title=".$title_p1." min='10' max='100'></td>"; 
echo "<td><input type='text' style='width:24px; height:18px; font-size:10px;' name='actPsi_2' data-id-estudiante='".$persona['id_estudiante']."' pattern='[0-9]+([,\.][0-9]+)?' value=0 title=".$title_p2." min='10' max='100'></td>"; 
echo "<td><input type='text' style='width:24px; height:18px; font-size:10px;' name='actPsi_3' data-id-estudiante='".$persona['id_estudiante']."' pattern='[0-9]+([,\.][0-9]+)?' value=0 title=".$title_p3." min='10' max='100'></td>"; 
echo "<td><input type='text' style='width:24px; height:18px; font-size:10px;' name='actPsi_4' data-id-estudiante='".$persona['id_estudiante']."' pattern='[0-9]+([,\.][0-9]+)?' value=0 title=".$title_p4." min='10' max='100'></td>"; 
echo "<td><input type='text' style='width:24px; height:18px; font-size:10px;' name='actPsi_5' data-id-estudiante='".$persona['id_estudiante']."' pattern='[0-9]+([,\.][0-9]+)?' value=0 title=".$title_p5." min='10' max='100'></td>";
```

Ahora, veo que realizas un ajax por cada evento change de los inputs, esto le pega al performance de la aplicación, los datos que necesites para realizar algún cálculo deben estar disponibles previamente ya sea que se guarden en variables globales después de traerlos con un único ajax o traerlos al cargar la pagina y guardarlos en inputs de tipo hidden: `<input type='hidden' id='idDatoNecesario_1' value='0.01' \>` para poder utilizarlos cada vez que se requieran: `$("#idDatoNecesario_1").val()`, así tu aplicación sera mas rápida mostrar la información que necesites si es el caso.

Comment: La cuestión que veo es que estos inputs que se crean, van dentro de un bucle, con lo cual quedarían varios con name="actPsi_1" o "actPsi_2" si me entiendes?, esto es lo que quiero lograr una planilla de notas donde el usuario va digitando las notas y de una vez te va mostrando la nota definitiva mira la imagen: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7PMB67v2922TlZKMjM2Y3lSV2M/view?usp=sharing]  los inputs encerrados en el cuadro naranja son los que se crean con "echo"

Comment: Pudes referenciar el cuadro de texto al que necesitar agregar el valor en otro atributo data en los inputs: `data-target-id-text='DC_P_".$i."'` 
y cambia el id del input DC_P: `id='DC_P_".$i."`
para que en el evento change puedas llamar a ese text y hacer el calculo:
`var idDC_P = $(this).attr("data-target-id-text"); $("#"+ idDC_P).val("Nuevo valor")`