# Cómo mostrar el "title" de un enlace

Tags: php, jquery, html

Tengo un menú con `href` el cual es cargado desde una base de datos. Con jQuery espero un click en el elemento pero solo me muestra el contenido del `title` del primer elemento. Lo ideal sería que mostrara lo del elemento presionado. Adjunto el código:

Esto es un extracto de PHP donde cargo el menú:

```
$menu.='<ul class="nav nav-tabs">';
while ($imprime=$resultado->fetch_assoc()) {        
    $menu.='<li role="presentation"><a id="menu" href="#" title="'.$imprime["DESCRIPCION"].'">'.$imprime["DESCRIPCION"].'</a></li>';
}
$menu.='</ul>';
```

Y acá el jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(documentoListo)

function documentoListo() {
    $("#formuNewUser").submit(ingresarUsuario)
    $("#menu").click(mostrarOcultar)
}
function mostrarOcultar(){
    var title = $("#menu").attr("title")
    console.log(title)
}
```

Comment: **NO** puedes tener más de un elemento en tu página web con el mismo ID. Tendrías que usar clases en su defecto. Tampoco entiendo porque quieres hacer click en el menú una vez esté la página cargada... Al tener ahora todos los li con el mismo ID es por eso por lo que solo te muestra el del primero.

Comment: en un proyecto anterior tenia algo parecido pero con botones, el proyecto ya no lo tengo (mi pc se daño y no funciona), como decía funcionaba con un ciclo que esperaba los click y los contaba y algo mas pero no recuerdo bien, en ese momento me ayudo un profesor

Comment: Probé como dices con clases pero igual muestra lo mismo solo imprime el primer elemento todo el tiempo

Comment: @FranciscoRomero **Sí** es posible tener varios elementos con el mismo ID o Clase. Sólo es cuestión de organizar la forma en la que se presentan.
Por ejemplo (div#algo span#texto) y (div#algonuevo span#texto) es válido el uso del mismo ID para varios elementos.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme#comment37983004_5611975  Siendo la traducción parcial: *Es posible tener múltiples elementos con el mismo ID. No suele ser una buena práctica, pero tiene usos ocasionales. Utilice sus selectores con un padre, donde los IDs bajo el padre serían únicos.*

Comment: @MáximaAlekz Bueno, la verdad que desconocía esa propiedad aunque es muy poco recomendable para evitar confusiones y solamente ocurre en ocasiones muy concretas. En este caso concreto el OP no estaba usando esa opción tampoco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

como dice Francisco, NO podes tener mas de un elemento con el mismo id. Hay varias formas de resolver lo que necesitas, una seria agregando onclick:

```
while ($imprime=$resultado->fetch_assoc()) {        
    $menu.='<li role="presentation"><a id="menu" href="#" title="'.$imprime["DESCRIPCION"].'" onclick="mostrarOcultar();">'.$imprime["DESCRIPCION"].'</a></li>';
}
```

Pero ya que estas tratando de seleccionar con jquery, vamos a la forma correcta de hacerlo

Primero deberías leer un poco sobre los selectores:

**El selector Id**

Selecciona un elemento del DOM a través de su Id

```
<div id="algunid"></div>
<script>
    var elemento = $("#algunid");
</script>
```

**El selector clase**

Selecciona un o mas elementos del DOM a través de su clase

```
<div class="main"></div>
<script>
    var elementosArray = $(".main");
</script>
```

> Podes leer esta info y un poco mas en mi respuesta:
>   [¿Como puedo operar con elementos con id dinámicos en jquery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75043/como-puedo-operar-con-elementos-con-id-din%c3%a1micos-en-jquery/75046#75046)

**Solución**

1. Agregar una clase al elemento del menú para que sea mas fácil seleccionarlo.
2. Agregar una función al onclick del elemento.

Entonces en el php:

```
$menu.='<ul class="nav nav-tabs">';
while ($imprime=$resultado->fetch_assoc()) {        
    $menu.='<li role="presentation"><a class="menu" href="#" title="'.$imprime["DESCRIPCION"].'">'.$imprime["DESCRIPCION"].'</a></li>';
}
$menu.='</ul>';
```

y en el js:

```
$(function() {
    $(".menu").click(function() {
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        console.log(title);
    });
});
```

Comment: gracias funciona a la perfeccion